# How to prove divergence elementarily

Tags: limits, cauchy-sequences

I have this problem: give an example of a real sequence $\;\{a_n\}\;$ with

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_{n+1}-a_n\right)=0\;,\;\;\text{but}\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\;\;\text{doesn't exist finitely}$$

The two classical examples I know, namely the harmonic series's partial sums sequence, and the sequence $\;\{\log n\}\;$ , both use either infinite series theory or the continuity of the function $\;\log x\;$ , needed to deduce the existence and value of the limit

$$\log(n+1)-\log n=\log\frac{n+1}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\log1=0$$

I'm trying to help somebody who has only studied sequences and their limits and is now in the Cauchy sequences part, but has *not* studied series nor functions and continuity.

Any example in this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also consider the sequence $(a_n)$ which is given by $a_n = \sqrt{n}$.

Note that everything you want to have can be shown elementarily. If $(a_n)$ would converge, then $(a_n^2)$ would also converge, but that is not possible. One can use a similar argument for the unboundedness of $(a_n)$. The convergence of $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \to 0$ can be shown easily, too.

Comment: I think this is a very nice answer and I cannot understand the downvote. Thank you @Slash. +1

Answer (score 1):

How about partial sums of
$$1+\frac12+\frac12+\frac13+\frac13+\frac13+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\cdots$$

Comment: Isn't partial sums related to series? I can't use series, otherwise I'd use directly the harmonic series. Only sequences, the squeeze theorem, arithmetic of limits, etc.  No functions at all, either. Thank you.

Comment: You can break out the partial sums for the student, so it doesn't have to use the terminology of partial sums.  I like this example, because its divergence is more obvious than for the partial sums of the harmonic series.

Comment: Good idea, @paw. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other example, how about
$$
\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4},\cdots
$$

Comment: Than you @Bombyx. +1